Envoy ratelimit service, cascading, subpaths and multiple granularity limits
I am struggling with configuring rate-limits for envoy rate-limiting service.
What I am trying to achieve:

Same match but two buckets (per minute/second)

descriptors:
  - key: host
    value: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
    rate_limit:
      unit: minute
      requests_per_unit: 10

  - key: host
    value: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
    rate_limit:
      unit: second
      requests_per_unit: 1


Match any subpath. I know this can be achieved by an action on the proxy side using some regex matching and adding a descriptor, but it seems a nightmare to maintain when you have many of these subpaths.

descriptors:
  - key: host
    value: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
    rate_limit:
      unit: minute
      requests_per_unit: 10
    descriptors:
    - key: path
      value: /subpath* #  /subpath/1 and /subpath/2 must share the same bucket
      rate_limit:
        unit: second
        requests_per_unit: 5


Using top-level descriptor limit when a more specific match is not found. In this example if I make a request to /subpath/2 for example the host rate-limit of 10 per minute is not applied.

descriptors:
  - key: host
    value: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
    rate_limit:
      unit: minute
      requests_per_unit: 10
    descriptors:
    - key: path
      value: /subpath/1
      rate_limit:
        unit: second
        requests_per_unit: 5

